# Для чего в классе Object некоторые методы имеют модификатор native?

Tags: java, c, jni

Зачем в *Java* нужен модификатор `native` и для чего в классе `Object` некоторые методы помечены им?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`native` указывает, что метод реализуется не в Java коде. В связке с JNI (Java Native Interface) идёт.

Как правило, подразумевается, что метод реализован в [c](/questions/tagged/c) коде. Работа с диском, сеть и т.п. реализованы в Си части, и Java обёртки вызывают эти методы.

Под рукой сейчас только Ubuntu. Пример на ней покажу.

Есть у вас основной Java файл **Main.java**:

```
public class Main {
    public native int intMethod(int i);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Main");
        System.out.println(new Main().intMethod(4));
    }
}
```

И `c` файл **Main.c**:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intMethod (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i) {
   return i * 2;
}
```

Ещё **Makefile** для сборки:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all:
    javac Main.java
    javah -jni Main
    gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I$${JAVA_HOME}/include -I$${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
    java -Djava.library.path=. Main

clean:
rm -f *.class *.so Main.h
```

Запустим всё это дело:

```
javac Main.java
javah -jni Main
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
java -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

На экране увидите: `8`.

Предварительные настройки:

1. Установлен jdk, самой собой.
2. Установить essential: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.
3. Путь прописать до Java. У меня это  `export JAVA_HOME='/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131'`

Пример показывает, как из Java вызвать Си код и вернуть результат.

## Когда это надо?

1. OS зависимые вещи.
2. Какие-то сложные вычисления. Часто математические библиотеки написаны на Си.

Comment: `В связке с JNI идёт` ... сторону тёмную используешь ты джавы.

Comment: @alexolut когда писал под Android, постоянно с jni работал ^_^